# Te3270 ruby code examples with x3270 driver and cucumber

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber

I'm trying to automate some testing task using cucumber under Ruby, connecting to a Mainframe platform using the TE3270 gem and the X3270 free driver, but a part to open the Mainframe screen cannot go further.

The code is running on Windows 7, Ruby 2.1.

This is the code that i have based on what appear in the TE3270 website:

```
require 'TE3270'

World(TE3270::ScreenFactory)

Before do
        @emulator = TE3270.emulator_for :x3270 do |platform|
        platform.executable_command = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\wc3270\wc3270.exe"'
        platform.host = 'mainframe.hostname'
        platform.max_wait_time = 5  # defaults to 10
        platform.trace = true # turns on trace output from the emulator
    end
end

Given /^my connection$/ do 
    my_screen = MainframeScreen.new(@emulator)

    my_screen.userid = 'my_mainframe_user'
    my_screen.password = 'my_mainframe_password'  
end

class MainframeScreen
    include TE3270

    text_field(:userid, 19, 36, 8)
    text_field(:password, 20, 36, 8)

    def login(username, password)
        self.userid = username
        self.password = password
    end
end
```

Any ideas ?

Regards,
Jonny

Answer (score 1):

I am not using cucumber right now, but I do have some working code for reading and writing.

I am using the [s3270](http://x3270.bgp.nu/Unix/s3270-man.html) displayless tool for writing screen-scraping scripts as the `platform.executable_command`. (On Mac right now, but I have also used it on Windows in the past; you just need to [download](http://x3270.bgp.nu/download.html) and [install from source](http://x3270.bgp.nu/Build.html).)

The key that made this work for me so far is the [wait_for_string](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/te3270/TE3270#wait_for_string-instance_method) function. I also recommend using the [text](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/te3270/TE3270#text-instance_method) method to dump the screen output.

```
require 'te3270'

class MainframeScreen
  include TE3270

  text_field(:welcome, 3, 34, 14, false)
  text_field(:application, 22, 21, 8)
end

emulator = TE3270.emulator_for :x3270 do |platform|
  platform.executable_command = 's3270'
  platform.host = '192.168.1.1'
end

screen = MainframeScreen.new(emulator)

screen.wait_for_string "Welcome to IBM", 3, 34
puts screen.welcome

screen.populate_screen_with :application => 'TSO'
screen.send_keys TE3270.Enter
```